# Duplicate output rows

Tags: gnuplot

I tried to plot this dataset, but got extra lines on the output.

Here is my dataset, feedings.data:

```
2023-01-22 09:00
2023-01-22 11:40
2023-01-22 13:30
2023-01-22 19:40
2023-01-22 22:15
2023-01-23 04:45
2023-01-23 07:45
2023-01-23 10:15
2023-01-23 12:30
2023-01-23 13:30
2023-01-23 17:45
2023-01-23 22:45
2023-01-24 02:45
2023-01-24 07:30
2023-01-24 10:30
2023-01-24 13:30
2023-01-24 17:45
```

Here is a simplified version of my gnuplot program:

```
reset
set   output "./feedings.png"
set   xdata time
set   format x "%H:%M"
set   ytics time;
set   format y "%Y-%m-%d"

plot "./feedings.data" using (timecolumn(2, "%H:%M")):(timecolumn(1, "%Y-%m-%d")) with points;
```

Here is the output:
[image]
How can I get rid of the superfluous empty lines on the y axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

```
set ytics 86400
unset mytics
```

- Set the major ytic distance manually, i.e. 86400 seconds are one day.
  If your y-range is more than just 2 or 3 days the gnuplot auto-tics should reduce the number of major tics automatically.
- Remove the minor ytics via `unset mytics`.

I would use the newer syntax without `set xdata time`, but `set format x "%H:%M" timedate` and `set format y "%Y-%m-%d" timedate`.

**Script:**

```
### customize timedate format ytics
reset session

$Data <<EOD
2023-01-22 09:00
2023-01-22 11:40
2023-01-22 13:30
2023-01-22 19:40
2023-01-22 22:15
2023-01-23 04:45
2023-01-23 07:45
2023-01-23 10:15
2023-01-23 12:30
2023-01-23 13:30
2023-01-23 17:45
2023-01-23 22:45
2023-01-24 02:45
2023-01-24 07:30
2023-01-24 10:30
2023-01-24 13:30
2023-01-24 17:45
EOD

set format x "%H:%M" timedate
set format y "%Y-%m-%d" timedate
set offsets 0,0,0.5,0.5
set ytics 86400
unset mytics

plot $Data u (timecolumn(2, "%H:%M")):(timecolumn(1, "%Y-%m-%d")) \
      w p pt 7 lc "red" ti "Data"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]